# Unable to catch exception in Azure Worker Role

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-worker-roles

I am attempting to create an Azure Worker Role to download emails and store them in a database. I'm throwing some exceptions when I can't connect or authenticate with a mail server, but catching these is not working.

The exceptions I throw are not being caught by the try catch block. Why is that?

**The RunAsync method of my worker role:**

```
private async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // TODO: Replace the following with your own logic.
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Trace.TraceInformation("Working");

            var emailManager = new EmailManager();
            var emails = new List<Email>();

            try
            {
                emails = emailManager.GetNewEmails("outlook.office365.com", 993, "email", "password");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.TraceInformation("Error");
            }

            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }
```

**EmailManager.GetNewEmails()**

```
public List<Email> GetNewEmails(string server, ushort port, string username, string password)
    {
        var imapClient = new ImapClient(server, port, username, password, false);
        if (!imapClient.Connect())
            throw new Exception("Unable to connect to server.");
        if (!imapClient.Authenticate())
            throw new Exception("Unable to authenticate with server.");

        var messages = imapClient.GetMessages();
        var emails = Mapper.Map<List<MailMessage>, List<Email>>(messages);

        return emails;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that your `EmailManager()` constructor is not throwing the exception?

Comment: Put while loop inside a try catch. This will make sure other statements are not throwing exception.

Comment: @BrendanGreen I've got breakpoints being hit inside GetNewEmails() and by stepping through the code I get to imapClient.Connect() and then it stops. That's because that's where I'm throwing the exception which ends up not being caught by the catch block in my RunAsync method. I'm trying to figure out why it's not being caught in the catch block.

Comment: @MukulVarshney I'll attempt that, but I am hitting GetNewEmails() and stepping through code leads me up to imapClient.Connect()

Comment: @MukulVarshney As I suspected encasing the while loop in try catch did not help. The exception I throw after imapClient.Connect() is not being caught at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out the thread is not actually crashing, but hanging indefinitely. This appears to be a bug in the e-mail library I'm using, OpaqueMail, which occurs when you attempt to establish a non-SSL POP3 or IMAP connection. I've raised a bug with the developer on their GitHub page.

When I force an SSL connection everything works as expected and exceptions that are thrown are caught as they should be.

So to sum it up, a bug caused the thread to hang, the problem was never related to Azure, asynchronous methods or exception handling. It was an OpaqueMail bug all along.